# How to check if a combo of two fields in one table appears in another table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables, **Table1** and **Table2** which have in common two fields **EmployeeId** and **ProjectId**

**Table1**

| EmployeeId | ProjectId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 |
| 2 | 222 |
| 3 | 333 |
| 4 | 444 |

**Table2**

| ProjectId | EmployeeId |
| --- | --- |
| 222 | 5 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 444 | 4 |
| 333 | 2 |
| 555 | 8 |

I want to write a query that creates a column called 'Match' indicating whether an EmployeeId/ProjectId combo that appears in **Table1** also appears in **Table2**. For example the first and fourth rows of **Table1** should be indicated as matches since those combos appear in **Table2** The final output should look like the following :

| EmployeeId | ProjectId | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | yes |
| 2 | 222 | no |
| 3 | 333 | no |
| 4 | 444 | yes |

If anyone knows how to write this sort of query, I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join on the field of employeeId and ProjectId.
So you will use table1 as the left table, and join table2 as the right table. Then where table2 fails to join, you will get NULL and you can write NO for the match...

```sql
SELECT
  t1.employeeId,
  t1.projectId,
  CASE
    WHEN t2.employeeId IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' 
    END AS match
FROM
  table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN
  table2 AS t2
  ON t2.employeeId = t1.employeeId
  AND t2.projectId = t2.projectId
```

The left table, table1, will serve as the 'permanent' data that populates in the results-set, ie. you will get the whole table (t1) in the output.
The right table, table2, will only join, when there is a condition that employeeId matches AND projectId matches.
Because we choose a left join, the records from t1 that don't have a match in t2 will result in NULL from t2.